# Job Solr.CoreWatcher threw an unhandled Exception while trying to run Alfresco application

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-share, solr4

I am trying to run Alfresco application (Alfresco 5.2) but for some reason I am getting this kind of error:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2023-03-28 13:37:00,542  ERROR [quartz.core.JobRunShell] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@3f1a7396_Worker-1] Job Solr.CoreWatcher threw an unhandled Exception:
 org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 02280000 d_dictionary.model.err.parse.failure
        at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.createModel(M2Model.java:113)
        at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.createModel(M2Model.java:99)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.loadPersistedModels(ModelTracker.java:121)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.<init>(ModelTracker.java:92)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.registerForCore(CoreWatcherJob.java:132)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.execute(CoreWatcherJob.java:82)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
Caused by: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Error accessing document
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.XMLPullReaderFactory$XMLPullReader.next(XMLPullReaderFactory.java:293)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.toStart(UnmarshallingContext.java:446)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:2750)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshallingContext.java:2900)
        at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.createModel(M2Model.java:108)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.XMLPullReaderFactory$XMLPullReader.next(XMLPullReaderFactory.java:291)
        ... 11 more
2023-03-28 13:37:00,544  ERROR [quartz.core.ErrorLogger] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@3f1a7396_Worker-1] Job (Solr.CoreWatcher threw an exception.
 org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 02280000 d_dictionary.model.err.parse.failure]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:227)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.dictionary.DictionaryException: 02280000 d_dictionary.model.err.parse.failure
        at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.createModel(M2Model.java:113)
        at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.createModel(M2Model.java:99)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.loadPersistedModels(ModelTracker.java:121)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.<init>(ModelTracker.java:92)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.registerForCore(CoreWatcherJob.java:132)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.execute(CoreWatcherJob.java:82)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Error accessing document
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.XMLPullReaderFactory$XMLPullReader.next(XMLPullReaderFactory.java:293)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.toStart(UnmarshallingContext.java:446)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:2750)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshallingContext.java:2900)
        at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2Model.createModel(M2Model.java:108)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.XMLPullReaderFactory$XMLPullReader.next(XMLPullReaderFactory.java:291)
        ... 11 more
```

This is snapshot of my current environment which is working fine.
I do not know what could be the problem here?
The server starts at the end, but when I try to log in I cannot do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like solr either has no access to the model cache dir or there are empty/corrupted model files. Please check that there are no 0-byte xml files in the solr model cache dir.

Comment: It helped, server starts without any errors in logs, but for some reason search still won't work. When I try to search I am getting error like this `ERROR [solr.core.SolrCore] [http-bio-8443-exec-7] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field: "boolean@sd@{http://www.adama.com/model/document/1.0}documentStudyNotification" at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getField(IndexSchema.java:1200)`. What could be the problem now? Thanks! @Heiko Robert

Comment: I guess there are solr documents in your index which no longer have a model in your model cache dir. Try to reindex now following the procedure you describe in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75875629/1898538)

Comment: so please just mark the answer as solution for the problem you described here