# How to do re-index of Solr in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am working with Alfresco Share 5.2 and currently trying to do re-index of Solr on Test server.

Steps which I covered are:

1. stop Alfresco service;
2. delete content from model directory;

```
root@ip-10-200-2-88:/opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr4/model# rm *
```

3. delete content from index directories inside archive and workspace folders;

```
root@ip-10-200-2-88:/opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr4/index/archive/SpacesStore/index# rm *
root@ip-10-200-2-88:/opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr4/index/workspace/Spacestore/index# rm *
```

4. start Alfresco service.

After that I check the logs and I am getting this kind of error:

```
 ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@2c708e13_Worker-1] Model tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02290000 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1181)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:256)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:236)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.registerForCore(CoreWatcherJob.java:145)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.execute(CoreWatcherJob.java:82)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
2023-03-29 09:35:13,375  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@2c708e13_Worker-2] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02290001 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1181)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:256)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:174)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:190)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:54)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
2023-03-29 09:35:13,392  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@2c708e13_Worker-1] Model tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02290002 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1181)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:256)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:236)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.registerForCore(CoreWatcherJob.java:145)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreWatcherJob.execute(CoreWatcherJob.java:82)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
2023-03-29 09:35:15,016  ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@2c708e13_Worker-7] Model tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02290006 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1181)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:256)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:214)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:236)
        at org.alfresco.solr.component.EnsureModelsComponent.prepare(EnsureModelsComponent.java:87)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:292)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
        at org.alfresco.solr.Cloud.getResponse(Cloud.java:165)
        at org.alfresco.solr.Cloud.getSolrDocumentList(Cloud.java:149)
        at org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer.getDocsWithUncleanContent(SolrInformationServer.java:722)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ContentTracker.doTrack(ContentTracker.java:81)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:190)
```

I checked again those folders, but for some reason indexes are mising, the Solr didn't rebuilt them.

Comment: Are you sure, you certificates/truststores are still valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are 4 removes I use to do when a made a FULL-REINDEX. *Don't do all of them if you only need a simple reindex. Before doing this actions please read [heiko-robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898538/heiko-robert) comments to know better what actions are you performing and if you really want them.*

You did 3 of them.

This one is OK:

```
rm -rf /opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr4/model/*
```

I use to remove index folder too:

```
rm -rf /opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr4/index/workspace/SpacesStore/*
rm -rf /opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr4/index/archive/SpacesStore/*
```

You forgot this one, solr 4 contents:

```
rm -rf /opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr4/content/*
```

Comment: This is not a fix to the problem described above. Removing the content cache is just slowing down the reindexing since the metadata and text extraction has to be retrieved again from the repository.

Comment: I suggested 2 actions, remove all indexes folder (not only content of the index folder)  and remove solr contents.  Maybe is not needed as you say, but in my opinion, this is part of a full reindex.

Comment: The error stack is caused by something else. If someone finds this question by the error, your suggestion is not the solution. To reindex I would only suggest to remove the index itself. It should not harm to clean the models dir by default but I would not recommend to always clean the content dir since it's the cache for already extracted metadata. So clean that dir only, if you don't trust this cache for any reason.