# SOLR undefined field boolean exception Alfresco

Tags: solr, alfresco, alfresco-share, solr4

I am having problems with Alfresco Share 5.2 and solr4 search.
I did full re-index and server stars without any errors in logs.

When I try to search I get 0 as result, it won't work and in logs this error apears:

```
2023-03-30 08:55:11,514 ERROR [solr.core.SolrCore] [http-bio-8443-exec-25] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field: "boolean@sd@{http://www.adama.com/model/document/1.0}documentStudyNotification" 
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getField(IndexSchema.java:1200) 
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getTermCounts(SimpleFacets.java:393) 
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getTermCounts(SimpleFacets.java:366) 
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets$2.call(SimpleFacets.java:592) 
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets$2.call(SimpleFacets.java:583) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets$1.execute(SimpleFacets.java:537) 
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getFacetFieldCounts(SimpleFacets.java:608) 
at org.apache.solr.request.SimpleFacets.getFacetCounts(SimpleFacets.java:264) 
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent.process(FacetComponent.java:107) 
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:319) 
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) 
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1976) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:418) 
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
at org.alfresco.web.scripts.servlet.X509ServletFilterBase.doFilter(X509ServletFilterBase.java:144) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What could be the problem? Should I change something in my solr config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's more or less the same issue for which you created the other questions here on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75875629/how-to-do-re-index-of-solr-in-alfresco), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867188/job-solr-corewatcher-threw-an-unhandled-exception-while-trying-to-run-alfresco-a)).

It looks like you removed models which are still referenced.

The alfresco solr tracker always requests the available models from the repository on startup. So either you removed cached models on a running solr instance or you removed a model/module (adama) from your alfresco repository although there are still nodes in the repository refererencing this model.

One technical fix would be a new reindex to not index metadata which has no definition in the repository *but* you may want to put back the model into the repository config since there are still nodes in Alfresco referencing the `http://www.adama.com/model/document/1.0` model. Once the model is back in your repo, the solr tracker will retrieve it on next restart.

Comment: It helped once again. Now everything works as expected! Thanks. @Heiko Robert